# Can you connect your ipad to the headphone jack in your guitar amplifier and record using garageband?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, amplifiers, garage-band

I have a marshall mg 15fx amplifier and no audio interface or mic.

Comment: I would suggest to follow [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: This might be useful: https://www.reddit.com/r/ipad/comments/3nv5eq/can_the_headphone_port_be_used_for_audio_in/?utm_source=xpromo&utm_medium=amp&utm_name=amp_comment_iterations&utm_term=control_1&utm_content=post_body